# Calculate percent from data frame with several species, treatments and variables using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

**Problem**

Make a new row containing percent

**Data**

```
 df<- data.frame(
     species   = c ("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
     number    = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2),
     treatment = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
     variable  = c ("x","y","x","y","x","y","x","y","x","y","x","y","x","y","x","y"),
     value = sample(1:16)
    )
```

**Question**

I would like to calculate percent for a species of a given number and treatment.. I.e. variable x and y (two first lines) should sum to 100%.

I tried with dplyr:

```
result <- df%>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    mutate(percent = value*100/sum(value))

test<-subset(result,variable=="x")
sum(test[,6]) # sums to 100%
```

"test" is wrong because it’s the percent of all x across both species and both treatment.

**desired output**

```
 species number treatment variable value    percent
    A      1         0        x     40         40
    A      1         0        y     60         60
    A      2         0        x      1         10
    A      2         0        y      9         90
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(percent= value*100/sum(df$value))`

Comment: No, that was only my attempt. Any solution is fine..

Comment: I meant `sum(df$value)` and not `sum(value)`

Comment: Compare the output of @akrun's approach and yours: they are different. The way you described it, akrun's approach gives you the correct solution.

Comment: can you show a desired output that you want

Comment: When you do with `sample`, please use the `set.seed` so that it becomes reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer that uses `tidyr`:

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr) 

df %>% spread(variable, value) %>% 
        mutate(percent.x = x / (x+y), 
               percent.y = y / (x+y))
```

Here also is a `dplyr`-only solution:

```
df %>% group_by(number, treatment, species) %>% 
        mutate(percent = 100 * value / sum(value))
```

Your problem was that you were doing `group_by()` on exactly the wrong variables.  Since you want the percentage defined within a particular `(number, treatment, solution)` combination, but to vary across your `variable`, you should `group_by()` the former, not the latter.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had tried “group_by(number, treatment, species)” and it didn’t work.. Anyways, now it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I'm using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)

DT_output <- DT[,list(value=sum(value)),by=c('species', 'number', 'treatment', 'variable')]
DT_temp <- DT[,list(sum=sum(value)),by=c('species', 'number', 'treatment' )]

T_output <- merge(DT_output, DT_temp, by = c('species', 'number', 'treatment'))

DT_output[, percent := 100 * value / sum]

setorder(DT_output, species,treatment,number,variable)
DT_output
```